# Two dimensional dynamic char array cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I need to create global n fields of 20 characters in c++ 11 as simple as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char(*a)[20];
int main(){
    int n;
    do{
        cout << "N= ";
        cin >> n;
    } while (n<1);

    a[20] = new char[n][20];

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) cout << a[i] << endl;
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this code correct? By correct I mean is this n fields/strings of 20 chars.
I want to make sure I don't write in random memory parts.

The array a has to be global because I use it in some custom functions later.

Comment: As this is C++ I would suggest using a `std::array<std::string, 20> a;` and  not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For n strings of 20 characters:

```
char** a;
int main()
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        cout << "N= ";
        cin >> n;
    }
    while(n < 1);

    a = new char*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = new char[20];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        memset(a[i], 0, 20);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Homework is so much easier when you can get random strangers on the internet to do it for you!

Comment: It's his decision if he want's to learn something or just pass.

Comment: A better answer would have provided an explanation of what was needed and why, instead of just writing the code ready to drop in.

Comment: There are many explanations on the internet. I still think he just wants to have his homework done instead of learn how does it work.

Comment: This is not a homework, our class is very porly execuded and provides little to no explanation on how code works. I passed the class and now i'm looking into the logic of the language. Sadly , here , i still got just the code and no explanation.

Comment: English is my second language, and it's complicated to google tehnical stuff of the c++ language.
I know it can be done with vectors, and it can be done without vectors. Every answer i found is using vectors. I want the solution without vectors.

Comment: Well, English is my second language as well. I must disagree with you that it's complicated to find some tutorials for C++ beginners. I have decided one day 2 years ago that I want to make 3D FPS game and I started learning from scratch. You can learn the best by trying, trying and figuring out how things work. If you are really stuck and ask for help, someone give you an answer - either code or explanation, most of the time, code is better for you, because you will understand it your way. If someone explained you everything, you wouldn't learn anything, just memorize something.

Comment: I am also learning some game basics in openGL. For about 3 months now. I work slowly because I experiment. I am familiar with the learning to code 101 and have learned proggraming logic and basics. As my question is language specific, the answer provided atm helped me research further into the language. Like wtf are ** and char*. I am putting the time to learn. I hope you understand that. Aftet all what is this site for that to ask questions like this?

Comment: Ma prefferd method of learing code is to look at existing pieces and examining the parts of code or language. This provided me the base, now comes the learing part. I am not just looking for answers to a goddamn homework. If you want to see some of my coding work you can contact me at redzicleon@gmail.com . As i am coding as a begginer for 2-3 years now. My base was MC coding for the MSP420G2553.

Comment: I'm glad then it's not some homework but you actually want to learn something. MSP420G2553 is something like an Arduino, right?